# Can't select future dates in phonegap app after iOS 7 upgrade

Tags: ios, cordova, datepicker, ios7

I am using phone gap date picker plugin for iOS, which was working fine, but can't select future date after iOS7 upgrade .
This is my js code,

```
     // Handling for iOS and Android
$('.appointmentTime').on('click', function(e) {
       var currentField  = $(this);
        window.plugins.datePicker.show((function() {
            var o = {
                date: new Date(),
                mode: 'time', // date or time or blank for both
                allowOldDates: true
            };
            if (myConfig.deviceType === myConfig.deviceTypeEnum.IOS) {
                o.allowFutureDates = true;
            }
            return o;
        })(), function(returnDate) {
            var selectedDate;
        selectedDate = new Date(returnDate);   
            currentField.blur();
        });
}
```